# Как проверить отсутствие ответа?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться, есть следующий код контроллера

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ContentResult> Auction([FromQuery] int[] ids, [FromQuery] string platfrom, AuctionModel auctionModel)
        {
            var partners = _AdCampaignMsSqlBl.GetRtbPartners(ids);
            var result = await _rtbService.GetAuctionResult(partners.Values, auctionModel);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
            {
                return new ContentResult
                {
                    Content = result,
                    ContentType = "application/xml",
                    StatusCode = 200
                };
            }
            else
                return new ContentResult
                {
                    Content = null,
                    ContentType = "application/xml",
                    StatusCode = 200
                };

        }
```

Необходимо добавить фильтр, в которым будет проверяться равен ли `ContentResult` значению `null` или нет.
Пробовал вот такой фильтр, но в `HttpContext.Response` не нашел нужного мне свойства

```
public class MetricFilterPlatfrom : ResultFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
            if(context.HttpContext.Response != null)
                // Код при true
            else
               // Код при false

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, правильно это или нет, но я бы пошел другим путем - просто задал бы нужный тип ответа.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Auction([FromQuery] int[] ids, [FromQuery] string platfrom, AuctionModel auctionModel)
{
    var partners = _AdCampaignMsSqlBl.GetRtbPartners(ids);
    var result = await _rtbService.GetAuctionResult(partners.Values, auctionModel);

    if (result?.Length > 0)
    {
        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = result,
            ContentType = "application/xml",
            StatusCode = 200
        };
    }
    else return new NoContentResult(); // 204 No Content
}
```

Comment: Идея хорошая, но хотелось бы реализовать ответ с пустым `Content`, если ничего не придумаю, то воспользуюсь Вашим предложением, спасибо

Comment: @Nikita 204 - это и есть ответ с пустым Content. Или вам не 204 надо, тогда что именно? По спецификации HTTP ответ с пустым Content не может быть 200.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, правда если взять код выше, то будет ошибка преобразования типа ContentResult к NoContentResult, но я пошел по другому благодоря Вашему ответу и все вродебы заработало)

Comment: @Nikita я исправил код в ответе